# Checked as default for set_checkbox in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Using Codeigniter 3.  The set_checkbox works fine for me, except I can't get the default to be checked.

I've have tried what was suggested in other posts, but I still can't get it to work...

For debugging I've boiled it down to the following...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="xyz" value="1" <?php echo set_checkbox( "xyz", "1", TRUE ) ?> XYZ
```

and

```
<input type="checkbox" name="xyz" value="1" <?php echo set_checkbox( "xyz", "1", 1 ) ?> XYZ
```

Neither works for me.  Suggestions?

Comment: Your input tag is not closed. Add /> after ?>

Comment: Thank you, Francisco,  Wow, you have a good eye.  I made change.  Alas, it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, for a page where you might be creating or updating something ($obj in this case), I do this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="xyz" value="1" <?php 

    // On page load, if obj has '1' for xyz, apply check
    $default_value = ( isset( $obj['xyz'] ) && $obj['xyz'] == '1' );

    echo set_checkbox( 'xyz', '1', $default_value );
?> />
```

This $obj is a thing in the database, and so this works for me if I am creating or updating $obj.

I'm not sure if this is what you're after, but I use this every day.

Comment: Thank you, Brian. I actually do that in my application. I have no problem trying to determine if I want the default to be checked or not. My problem is simpler than that.  It doesn’t matter what I set as the third argument to set_checkbox.  It always returns nothing.

Comment: I need to clarify that last response.  It always returns nothing initially.  If the the post doesn’t pass form_validation, it does return checked, if indeed the checkbox was checked.

Comment: If you take a look at the set_checkbox methods in Form_validation.php and the form helper, it may help you figure out what's going on. For instance, if your request method is post but there was no posted data, set_checkbox will always return an empty string.

Comment: Thanks again, Brian.  I will review those methods.

This is hard to describe, but this is prior to a post.  This is the initial presentation of the form.  Once a user does initiate a post, everything works as I expect.  It's the initial presentation of the page.  I can't think of what good a "default" value would be after the first post.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start this answer with stating that I am in no way a PHP expert, nor can I divine the original author's intent.  If that doesn't bother you, please continue to read :) ...

Following Brian's advice, I looked at the set_checkbox code, and what I found was the following.

A: Codeigniter 3 has two copies of this function.  One is in system/libraries/Form_Validation.php.  The second is in system/helpers/form_helper.php.

B: The one in form_helper.php contains what I would guess is a bug.

I will elaborate on B:  The last line of set_checkbox says

```
return ( $default === TRUE) ? ' checked="checked" : '';
```

Unfortunately it never gets that far. Just before that statement is this...

```
if ($CI->input->method() === 'post') 
{
    return ($input === $value) ? ' checked="checked"' : ''; 
}
```

In my case the if statement was true, but "$input === $value" was never true, so I always getting a return of ''.  I changed it to read...

```
if ($CI->input->method() === 'post')
{
   return ($input === $value || $default === TRUE ) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
}
```

and now everything works as expected.

To be clear, I am not suggesting anybody change Codeigniter source code.  I am simply showing what worked for me.

Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Cheers,
Dennis

Answer (score 0):

Yes i have this problem, first who the hell wants a checkbox to be checked by default, and when you want to uncheck it it should remain unchecked if submit form and errors come.

i have resolved this by a trick i just got up.

I basically checked if the form was submitted and the set value was set like this

```
if($validation->getErrors() AND empty(set_value('status')))
{
    $seted_value = set_checkbox('status', set_value('status') == TRUE ? TRUE : FALSE, FALSE);
}
else
{
    $seted_value = set_checkbox('status', set_value('status') == TRUE ? TRUE : FALSE, TRUE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been asked a long time ago, but looking at the answers given here seems complex. I will answer this below:

```php
<input type="checkbox" name="xyz" value="1" <?php echo set_checkbox( "xyz", "1", false) ?> XYZ
```

The trick is the third parameter that is set to `false` .

That simply works. Anyone can try this and give feedback.